# How to aligned symbol in highcharts js?

Tags: highcharts

Now it looks like this:

[image: image description 1]

should be:

[image: image description 2]

```
    legend: {
        floating: true,
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 0,
        x: -20,
        width: 150,
        itemMarginTop: 12,
        itemMarginBottom: 12,
        alignItem: 'center',
        textAlign: '40px',
        itemStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'Inter',
            display: 'inline-block',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        labelFormatter() {
            return `<span style="font-size: 14px;color: #595959;font-weight: 400;">${this.name}</span><br><span style="font-size: 18px;color: #1C1C1E;font-weight: 600;">${this.y}</span>`
        } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In style options for legend `.highcharts-legend-item` you can change position of item, there is no directly options in Highcharts for adjust symbol position related to label. In this solution, you need to use [legend.useHTML](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML) to render legend items.

```
.highcharts-legend-item  {
    top: -10px !important;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6479m1y0/